# com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException: Too much redirect for

Tags: javascript, java, html, webclient

I have been getting this error

> com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException: Too much redirect for https://abc.xyz.com/help-and-support

I tried using `webClient.getCache().setMaxSize(0)` in the code but it did not help still getting the same error

Comment: Might this be caused by a webpage constantly redirecting to itself?

Comment: can this be tackled as it was working fine earlier. Suddenly it started shoeing up. can't it be ignored by setting up webclient options? @Ashley Frieze

Comment: It started showing up... did nothing else change? What are you using it to test? Could the page be doing redirects?

Comment: sorry for the typo earlier...Yes nothing has changed as far as code is considered. I guess page is doing the redirects.

Comment: It's the simplest answer. Has the page gone all weird?

Comment: I don't think as I can see the page is not changed

Comment: Facing the same error. And adding webClient.getCache().setMaxSize(0) doesn't help.